# Node cannot find an existing module or install new ones after copy on another computer

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, strapi, esbuild

I copied my project to a new computer (in fact, I use a synchronization service). I checked my folder with `ls -l` and I am the permissions seem right.

It is a strapi app, and when I execute `npm run develop`, here is what appears:

```
> strapi-hugo-blog@0.1.0 develop
> strapi develop

sh: 1: strapi: not found
```

I created my app with `npx create-strapi-app@latest strapi-hugo-blog`, so strapi was installed as a dependency that I updated later with `npm install` on the original computer.

So this is strange. When I execute a new `npm install`, here is what I get:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/me/my-app/node_modules/esbuild
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! node:internal/errors:491
npm ERR!     ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! <ref *1> Error: spawnSync /home/me/my-app/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild EACCES
npm ERR!     at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1110:20)
npm ERR!     at spawnSync (node:child_process:871:24)
npm ERR!     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:914:15)
npm ERR!     at validateBinaryVersion (/home/me/my-app/node_modules/esbuild/install.js:96:28)
npm ERR!     at /home/me/my-app/node_modules/esbuild/install.js:283:5 {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'spawnSync /home/me/my-app/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/me/my-app/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild',
npm ERR!   spawnargs: [ '--version' ],
npm ERR!   error: [Circular *1],
npm ERR!   status: null,
npm ERR!   signal: null,
npm ERR!   output: null,
npm ERR!   pid: 0,
npm ERR!   stdout: null,
npm ERR!   stderr: null
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Node.js v18.13.0
```

I found this error message nowhere on the internet.

When I just try to install strapi, I get more errors and warnings before (apparently it tries to use Strapi version 3, which is deprecated, whereas I have version 4 in my package-lock) but at the end appears the same message.

Executing npm with sudo does not change anything (and it shouldn't, as everything is installed locally).

As I'm using a synchronization service, I tried again on my original computer and everything works fine. Node is installed and is almost at the same version on both systems (v18.17.1 / v18.13.0).

Comment: It looks like your sync service might've messed up permissions. What does `stat -c "%U %G" my-app` say? or `stat -c "%U %G" node_modules` in `my-app`?

Comment: @ZacAnger my username and my group (twice the same name). As I said, I did a `ls -l` and everything looked normal

Comment: Back to the original computer: now I also get the `strapi: not found` error. So it's maybe not the synchronization process itself that broke my app, but something I did on the second computer. However, when I execute `npm install` on the first computer, it runs normally ("0 new packages installed etc").

Comment: What happens if you delete your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` in the new computer and then run `npm install`?

Comment: Ideally, you'd disable syncing node_modules. For example, you wouldn't commit those to github either. You should also ideally be running the exact same node version

Comment: Thank you for these advices @OneCricketeer. I'm not familiar enough with node yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to solve issues like this to delete your `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` files, and then do a clean install with `npm install`.

---

The reason copying over `node_modules` might not work is because both computers might be running different operating systems, or different OS versions, or different architecture, or different node/npm versions, and so on.

Comment: I think the lock file should be kept. That'll pin exact package versions and sha's... Otherwise, the "new machine" may pull a newer version if the package.json has any `^X.Y.Z` dependencies, or there could be a supply chain attack that overrides some npm package between installs